# Overlapping instance in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, metaprogramming

I'm reading code of the `HList` library. There is an `HBetween` class which is a type level function taking a `HNat` n and return a list of `HNat`s forming a range [HZero, n). I want to implement an other class `HRange`, it has an overload function `hRange :: l -> u -> r` which take a low bound `l` and a upper bound `u` and return a range [l, u). My code is below(to make the code more clear, the result of `hRange` is in reversed order, say (u, l] )

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, 
    FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}
module Data.HList.HNats where
import Data.HList.CommonMain
class (HNat l, HNat u) => HRange l u r | l u -> r where
  hRange :: l -> u -> r
instance HNat l => HRange l (HSucc l) (HCons l HNil) where
  hRange _ _ = undefined
instance HRange l u r => HRange l (HSucc u) (HCons u r) where
  hRange _ _ = undefined
```

I tried this code in ghci, something unexpected happened:

```
*Data.HList.HNats Data.HList> :load Data/HList/HNats
[1 of 1] Compiling Data.HList.HNats ( Data/HList/HNats.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Data.HList.HNats.
*Data.HList.HNats Data.HList> hRange hZero (hSucc hZero )

<interactive>:24:1:
    Overlapping instances for HRange
                                HZero (HSucc HZero) (HCons HZero HNil)
      arising from a use of `hRange'
    Matching instances:
      instance HNat l => HRange l (HSucc l) (HCons l HNil)
        -- Defined at Data/HList/HNats.hs:14:10
      instance HRange l u r => HRange l (HSucc u) (HCons u r)
        -- Defined at Data/HList/HNats.hs:20:10
    In the expression: hRange hZero (hSucc hZero)
    In an equation for `it': it = hRange hZero (hSucc hZero)
*Data.HList.HNats Data.HList>
```

I don't know why `hRange hZero (hSucc hZero )` could match instance `instance HRange l u r => HRange l (HSucc u) (HCons u r)`. Any explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Note that GHC gives the type of `hRange hZero (hSucc hZero)` as `HRange HZero (HSucc HZero) (HCons Zero HNil)`. Because the GHC instance matcher does not consider constraints before selecting matches, it just checks against `HRange l (HSucc u) (HCons u r)`. `l` can match anything, so matches `HZero`; `HSucc u` clearly matches `HSucc HZero`, as do `HCons u r` and `HCons HZero HNil`.

In general, as far as GHC is concerned, your second instance is a strict superset of the first, since the only difference in the right sides (thus ignoring the constraints `HNat l` and `HRange l u r`), when selecting an instance the first is the second with `r` restricted to be `HNil`. The normal approach to this problem is to throw in a phantom type or class to differentiate the right sides, although off the top of my head I do not see how to do that here.